# Unable to access USB modem web interface

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, dongle, usb-modem

When I plug in my NETGEAR(R) 341U USB Modem I used to be able to access it's webserver at a 192.168.1.1 IP address. That webserver had a whole webapp that let me make changes to the device.

The device has since gotten stuck in LTE mode and the mac will not recognize LTE as valid. So that 192.168.1.1 IP doesn't work any more. But if I could just start Apache or another webserver it uses with some command line option, I could probably get into the web interface and disable LTE. Any ideas how to start the webserver manually?

Comment: It surely has a reset button somewhere...?

Comment: @DanielB No it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out I just needed updated drivers from:

http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27019

Answer (score 0):

Check the TCP properties of the connection and make sure there is a gateway set at 192.168.1.1

Also, if you are using Chrome to access the "webserver", hold down the down arrow before pressing enter, as this will suppress a Google search and look locally.

The admin page webserver should be accessible no matter what state or lock the device is in.  It does not need LTE on/off or any cellular data connection to "serve" those configuration html pages -- unless of course it's truly broken.

But I doubt the latter.  I suspect the unit is waiting for a DHCP assignment, and your computer has no way of routing the 192.168.1.1 address because it has no idea where that is until that happens.

The solution probably lies in forcing a gateway address of 192.168.1.1 on the adapter using the TCP Iv4 properties with a local (255.255.255.0) subnet.  That should allow access to the configuration pages.

Again, it's a local device and only depends on the USB connection to access the configuration "webserver", as long as the computer can see it (i.e. route - where are you Netgear?) with a valid virtual adapter gateway and subnet.

On edit:  to specifically answer your question, no.  You can't start the webserver manually, because you can't even talk to it yet, even if there was a way.

Comment: thanks for your help, I was able to fix problem by getting latest drivers.

Comment: Great.  The drivers may have forced that virtual reset you were looking for.